# OpenVPN TAP binding order issue

Tags: openvpn, bindings, tap, adapter

I am running a 64bit Windows 7/8 AD environment using OpenVPN on remote computers to access our network/servers in our main office.

Typically, once we install OpenVPN on a new machine and configure the binding order (advanced setting in the network connections) so that OpenVPN TAP adapter is at the top of the binding order on a machine everything is fine.  The issue I am having is some how the binding order is changing periodically. I am not sure what is causing the binding order to change, but it is causing quite a few issues with my machines, one being that it's no longer communicating with my WSUS server.

If I manually change the binding order so that the TAP is at the top, everything if fine again.

My question is how can I statically set the binding order so that the OpenVPN TAP adapter is always at the top of the binding order.  I have tried messing with the "interface metric" but that does not seem to have any effect on the binding order.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Rich